# SyntaxError: invalid syntax EngineerIO.py", line 133 running simulation on IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

Works locally on mac. Gives syntax error below running on IBM Cloud using:
python-3.5.6

**Requirements.txt**

```
Flask==0.10.1
requests==2.12.4
flask-restful-swagger==0.19
flask-restplus==0.9.2
watson-developer-cloud>=1.3.5
python-dotenv==0.8.2
cloudant==2.12.0
UliEngineering==0.3.3
scipy>=0.5
toolz==0.10.0
numpy>=1.5
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "skill.py", line 16, in <module> from UliEngineering.SignalProcessing.Simulation import sine_wave File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/UliEngineering/SignalProcessing/Simulation.py", line 8, in <module> from UliEngineering.EngineerIO import normalize_numeric File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/UliEngineering/EngineerIO.py", line 133 self.unit_prefix_re = re.compile(f'({__unitprefix_set})+$') # $: Matched at end of numeric part ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: What does the `Requirements.txt` file have to do with the syntax error in a Python script? What are you actually doing? Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), reread about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: How is it deployed, Cloud Foundry, Kube, ...? What is the command? What buildpack if Cloud Foundry? What is the stack trace...?

Comment: Is that the latest version of UliEngineering? If not, try the latest. If so, try an older one.